# What is the standard file format required to be sent from Oracle Invoice Matching to Accounts Payable?

Tags: oracle, invoice, oracleapplications

I'm working on a project which needs to upload some invoices from Oracle Retail Invoice Matching to Accounts Payable. I'd like to use flat file but need to find out the exact format of it. I tried to go through documents of Oracle ReIM as well as AP but the only hint I get is

> For each invoice, the program should include values in the flat file
>   to populate the following foreign key columns in
>   AP_EXPENSE_REPORT_HEADERS:
>
> o VENDOR_ID
>
> o VENDOR_SITE_ID
>
> o ACCTS_PAY_CODE_COMBINATION_ID
>
> For each invoice distribution, include the value to populate the
>   Accounting Flexfield column in AP_EXPENSE_REPORT_LINES:
>
> o CODE_COMBINATION_ID
>
> In addition, if you are importing foreign currency invoices, include
>   information to populate the following columns in
>   AP_EXPENSE_REPORT_HEADERS:
>
> o DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE
>
> o DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_RATE
>
> o DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_DATE
>
> If this exchange rate information is the same for all invoices and
>   invoice distributions you import, you can include this information in
>   your SQL*Loader control file instead.
>
> Finally, ensure that your invoice flat file has the appropriate
>   information to populate AP_EXPENSE_REPORT_HEADERS and
>   AP_EXPENSE_REPORT_LINES as indicated in the preceding table
>   descriptions. If a value is note required for a column, you may leave
>   the column empty.

But I am not sure if this is the exact what I am looking for since according to it I would have to write a program to generate files manually. Considering both of ReIM and AP is Oracle's product. I suppose ReIM should be able to generate some kind of flat file that can be recognized by AP directly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!